# Is there a known minimum number of operations required to carry out an arbitrary combinatorial change to a system?

Tags: combinatorics

Imagine I have a chessboard. Let's say it has *n* identical pieces in some specific spatial configuration (configuration $a$). Now lets say I pick a new configuration (configuration $b$) of those $n$ pieces.

If each piece can only move one space at a time, is there a known formula that will define the minimum number of moves that it will take me to transform configuration $a$ into configuration $b$?

Obviously, I'm not really interested in a specific formula for this specific situation.

What I am looking for is a general theory that defines the minimum number of operations required to transform one configuration into another. This is something like the hamming distance used in information theory, but I am looking for an equivalent in combinatorics.

Comment: Hm, to me this looks closer related to Hausdorff distance than Hamming distance (though it's still quite something different).

Comment: The configurations can be viewed as vertices in a graph. Every move  is an edge. The "number of required operations" is the shortest path between vertex a and b. I've heard that the maximum distance about 20 (21?) for Rubic's Cube. But it is probably impossible to calculate such a general minimum for more complex games. I'd try to use Dynamic Programming (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) to actually find the shortest path,